# Import requests: python script in php

Tags: php, python, python-requests

I'm just having some trouble with my python script, is working fine, but at the moment I add this line to my script: 'import requests', it sends me the error:

> 'Message: Undefined offset: 0'

Here's the code of how I exec my python in php:

```
$lugar = $this->input->post('lugar');
$fecha = $this->input->post('fecha');
$colonia = $this->input->post('colonia');
$pais = $this->input->post('pais');
$num_ext = $this->input->post('num_ext');
$num_int = $this->input->post('num_int');
$localidad = $this->input->post('localidad');
$cp = $this->input->post('cp');
$rfc = $this->input->post('rfc');
$rfc_name = $this->input->post('rfc_name');
$estado = $this->input->post('estado');
$municipio = $this->input->post('municipio');
$calle = $this->input->post('calle');

exec("python listo.py '".escapeshellarg($lugar)."' '".$fecha."' '".$colonia."' '".$pais."' '".$num_ext."' '".$num_int."' '".$localidad."' '".$cp."' '".$rfc."' '".$rfc_name."' '".$estado."' '".$municipio."' '".$calle."'",$salida);
echo $salida[0];
```

The problem is I need to make a request to send my json:

```
r = requests.post('https://b.listo.mx/api/invoicing/generate_xml', json=generation_data,
                  headers={'Authorization': 'Token %s' % API_TOKEN}, verify=True)

response = r.json()[0]
xml, original_chain = response['xml'], response['original_chain']

print '-' * 80
print r.json()
```

Comment: I heard there's another way with urllib

Comment: Shouldn't you escape all arguments, and not just the first?

Comment: Yes, you're right.